# How to pass a parameter to an aggregation function in Dask

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I just discovered today that a sum of a column full of NaNs is 0 in `pandas` and `Dask` (why?!). I need a sum of all NaNs to be 0, because having NaNs means those values are missing, so their sum should be NaN as well.

From the documentation it appears that you have to pass `min_count = 0` to replicate this behaviour. However, I'm doing the sum into an aggregation that looks like this

```py
ddf.groupby("code").aggregate({'rain':'sum'}).compute()
```

Adding the argument `min_count` to the `aggregate` function seems to have no impact, while using a `lambda` in place of `'sum'` causes an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found out how to do this with custom aggregations.

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd

# We define our own sum that takes care of NaN values
custom_sum = dd.Aggregation('custom_sum',
                            lambda s: s.sum(min_count=1),
                            lambda s0: s0.sum(min_count=1))

ddf.groupby("code").aggregate({'rain':custom_sum}).compute()
```

Comment: Good to know there is a way of using a lambda function for aggregation in dask